# How to convert the raw sql command on Laravel ORM Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, orm

I have 4 tables, 1->user, 2->category, 3->comment, 4->post

I want to get the category for the related post that user already commented

```
SELECT kategoris.* FROM kategoris 
INNER JOIN yazis on yazis.kategori_id = kategoris.id 
INNER JOIN yorums on yorums.yazi_id = yazis.id
INNER JOIN users on users.id = yorums.user_id
where users.id = 1
```

[Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqx1N.png)

Comment: See: https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your models are setup, this is how the query should be with Eloquent

```php
$category = Post::whereHas('comments', function($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
        })->first()->category;
```

### Update:

This is how your models and table migrations should look
`User` has many posts and comments

```php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

`Category` has many posts

```php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

`Post` belongs to a category and a user, has many comments

```php
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

`Posts Table Migration`

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`Comment` belongs to a post and a user

```php
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

`Comments Table Migration`

```php
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Let's populate some data like this...
`Database Seeder`

```php
$user = factory(User::class)->create([]);
$category = Category::create([]);
$post = $user->posts()->create(['category_id' => $category->id]);
$post->comments()->create(['user_id' => $user->id]);
```

And get the category of the post that the authenticated user commented on with the query above...
Hope this helps :)